# tmux doesn't uninstall plugin

Tags: tmux

I installed a few plugins by adding lines to .tmux.conf

```
set -g @plugin 'noscript/tmux-mighty-scroll'
```

I installed with prefix I

I tried to scroll, and instead of doing its thing, it now ALWAYS says

`Can't find pane: mouse`

WORSE, I commented out the plugin line,
and hit PREFIX alt u,
to uninstall the plugins,
and now tmux continues to give that same error.

I confirmed the plugin is gone from .tmux folder,
and I can't see where else the memory of this plugin could be,

How do I get tmux to work the way it used to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing your config changes as not having an effect... and sourcing your `.tmux.conf` *should* do that but if it's not then you might need to close (`kill`, not `detach`) the sessions, and then start a new session with a new server using the updated config.

Regarding the error you're getting from that plugin... you may be able to solve that too... I'm not familiar with that particular plugin but there's a tmux config of `set -g mouse on` which may be relevant to that plugin's error.

---

edit: wait... you say:

> PREFIX alt u

...which I assumed you had mapped to `:source ~/.tmux.conf`. Is that so? Try running that (via prefix+`:`) if you haven't.

Comment: Ah yes, I had to close ALL of the sessions - thanks.

Comment: PREFIX alt u = uninstall missing plugins (tpm)
I did have a `set -g mouse on`, commenting that out has stopped that error.
Now I can't seem to scroll back into the console history - it scrolls the command history on the current line.  Anyway that is another problem...